# Trigger Azure Function every 3 months

Tags: azure-functions

I'm using a Time-Triggered function to run every 3 months / every 90 days.
I am doubting myself and not sure if my expression is good:

`0 0 12 1 1/3 ? *`

Would this **ncrontab** expression trigger the Azure Function every 3 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NCRONTAB expressions` should only contain six fields:

```
{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}
```

Maybe you can use this expression:

```
0 0 12 1 */3 *
```

You can refer to [NCRONTAB expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions).

Comment: Thanks, I'll use it! I actually found this tool for validation just now: https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/